# How to extract emails from a list of urls?

Tags: linux, url, web-crawler

I have a website with a list of urls. I need to make a command that would go on each link, go to the website and find an email address.

I need this command to do this for every url and search for every page on each url.

Is there any way I could achieve this ?

Thank you !

Here is the website with the url list : http://cabm.net/nos-membres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would encourage you to retrieve email addresses from databases.

That said, it is possible to achieve the desired effect by retrieving the set of html pages from each site (read downloading) then parsing through the string to retrieve strings in email format:

```
-whitespace-string@string.string-whitespace-
```

Results would be stored in an array of email addresses.

There isn't a single command to do this but it is possible to write a program to achieve the same.

The program itself also raises ethical issues on whether or not you're allowed to do that but that's a discussion for another time ;)